# how do i store the value of max(variable)?

Tags: c, binary-search

when i run it and after pressing the second 'n' it doesn't satisfy the logic and the reason is max returns 0(check the last printf) so how can i store the new value in max?

```
//A GAME FOR GUESSING YOUR NUMBER BY USING THE BINARY SEARCH ALGORITHM
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

int min=1;
int max,z,i;
char ans;

printf("\t\t\t***GUESSING GAME***\n");
printf("Let put a rang, the min number is 1, the max is? \n");
scanf("%d",&max);//--> 15

z=(min+max)/2; //the average


while(i<max)
{
 dis:
 printf("The number is %d? (y/n)\n",z); //--> z =( min(1) + max(15) ) / 2 = 8
 scanf("%s",&ans);

 if(ans=='n')
 {

     printf("Is %d too high? (y/n)\n",z);
     scanf("%s",&ans);
     //new range [1,8]
     if(ans=='y')
     {
         z=(min+z)/2;  //--> z =( min(1) + z(8) ) / 2 = 4
         goto dis;
     }
```

THIS "

```
     //new range [8,15]
     if(ans=='n')
     {
         z=(z+max)/2; //it should be z =( z(8) + max(15) ) / 2 = 11 
         goto dis;
     }
```

"

```
 }
 if(ans=='y')
 {
     printf("\\BINGO/");
```

the value of max will be 0

```
    // printf("max %d z %d",max,z);

 }
 i++;
}

}
```

Comment: The program has undefined behavior because in the condition of the loop there is used uninitialized variable i. while(i<max)

Comment: And instead of   scanf("%s",&ans); use scanf(" %c",&ans);  where there is a blank before the conversion specifier. %c (not %s)

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behavior because in the condition of the loop

```
while(i<max)
{
```

there is used an uninitialized variable `i`.

This call

```
 scanf("%s",&ans);
```

also invokes undefined behavior because there is passed address of one character while the call of `scanf` tries to read a string. For example if the user enters `'n'` scanf write to the addressed memory two characters `'n'` and `'\0`'.

Instead use

```
scanf(" %c",&ans);
```

Pay attention to the blank before the conversion specifier `%c`.

And do not use the goto statement. Instead use a loop.